# git status show the total number of changes in each file?

Tags: git

Is there a way when I do `git status` to show the total number of changes per file? All the solutions I see refer to `git diff`

I'd like something like:

```
MyFile.cpp (23)
AnotherFile.cpp (4)
```

etc

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `git diff`?

Comment: `git config alias.status2 = "diff --stat` Then you can do `git status2` 8p

Answer (score 5):

I believe you would need to use `git diff --stat`